# Create column header for csv file using vbs

Tags: csv, vbscript

How can I create a column header in csv file using vbs where users can later sort by clicking the column header? For example

```
USername        Password
Texas           123456
Mariot          abcdef
andres          abc123
```

I have created a csv file but still couldn't create the column header.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: By writing it to the file. If you can't do something so basic, what are you asking? Write your header, write the rest of the file.

Comment: Sorry I already edit the question. Can I create a csv file that can create a header column so when the user clicks on the USername, it will sort the name in ascend or descend. It that possible?

Comment: No. CSV is just plain text with a particular structure. Any kind of clicking or sorting is up to the program you're opening the file with.

Answer (score 0):

Program file *Music.hta*

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<OBJECT CLASSID="clsid:333C7BC4-460F-11D0-BC04-0080C7055A83"
    ID=dsoMacro5 WIDTH=0 HEIGHT=0>
    <PARAM NAME="DataURL" VALUE="music.txt">
    <PARAM NAME="UseHeader" Value="True">
    <PARAM NAME="FieldDelim" VALUE="&#09;">
    <PARAM NAME="Sort"  Value="Title">
</OBJECT>
<h3>My Music Database</h3>
<h4>Select a button to filter list</h4>
<p>To search for a word in the Title field use <i>* word *</i>. To search for the first word in a field use <i>Word *</i> or the last word use <i>* word</i>. To search for a string within a word or word use <i>*partialword*</i>. Searches are case sensitive.</i></p>
<p><INPUT Name=tb1 TYPE=Text Value=""> <INPUT ID=cmdNavFirst TYPE=BUTTON VALUE="     Search     " onclick="dsoMacro5.object.filter='Title=' + tb1.value;dsoMacro5.reset()"></p>
<p><INPUT ID=cmdNavFirst TYPE=BUTTON VALUE="   Sort Book   " onclick="dsoMacro5.object.sort='Book';dsoMacro5.reset()"></p>
<hr class="body">
<TABLE ID=tblMacro2 DATASRC=#dsoMacro5 OnRowEnter=Alert(tblMacro2.row)>
<THEAD>
<TR>
<TD WIDTH="20%"><b>Number</b></TD>
<TD WIDTH="60%"><b>Title</b></TD>
<TD WIDTH="20%"><b>Book</b></TD>
</TR>
</THEAD>
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD WIDTH="20%"><SPAN DATAFLD=Number></SPAN></TD>
<TD WIDTH="60%"><SPAN DATAFLD=Title></SPAN></TD>
<TD WIDTH="20%"><SPAN DATAFLD=Book></SPAN></TD>
</TR>
</TBODY>
</TABLE>
</body>
</html>
```

Data File *Music.txt*

```
Number  Title   Book
1   One A song
2   Two A another song
3   Three   A yet another song
4   Four    Yes it's a song
```

Answer (score 0):

This routine sorts

```
Set Arg = WScript.Arguments
set WshShell = createObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set Inp = WScript.Stdin
Set Outp = Wscript.Stdout

Sub Sort
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    If Arg(1) = "n" then
    With rs
        .Fields.Append "SortKey", 4 
        .Fields.Append "Txt", 201, 5000 
        .Open
        Do Until Inp.AtEndOfStream
            Lne = Inp.readline
            SortKey = Mid(Lne, Arg(3), Arg(4) - Arg(3))
            If IsNumeric(Sortkey) = False then
                Set RE = new Regexp
                re.Pattern = "[^0-9\.,]"
                re.global = true
                re.ignorecase = true
                Sortkey = re.replace(Sortkey, "")
            End If
            If IsNumeric(Sortkey) = False then
                Sortkey = 0
            ElseIf Sortkey = "" then
                Sortkey = 0
            ElseIf IsNull(Sortkey) = true then
                Sortkey = 0
            End If
            .AddNew
            .Fields("SortKey").value = CSng(SortKey)
            .Fields("Txt").value = Lne
            .UpDate
        Loop
        If Arg(2) = "a" then SortColumn = "SortKey ASC"
        If Arg(2) = "d" then SortColumn = "SortKey DESC"
        .Sort = SortColumn
        Do While not .EOF
            Outp.writeline .Fields("Txt").Value
            .MoveNext
        Loop
    End With
    ElseIf Arg(1) = "t" then
    With rs
        .Fields.Append "SortKey", 201, 260 
        .Fields.Append "Txt", 201, 5000 
        .Open
        Do Until Inp.AtEndOfStream
            Lne = Inp.readline
            SortKey = Mid(Lne, Arg(3), Arg(4) - Arg(3))
            .AddNew
            .Fields("SortKey").value = SortKey
            .Fields("Txt").value = Lne
            .UpDate
        Loop
        If Arg(2) = "a" then SortColumn = "SortKey ASC"
        If Arg(2) = "d" then SortColumn = "SortKey DESC"
        .Sort = SortColumn
        Do While not .EOF
            Outp.writeline .Fields("Txt").Value
            .MoveNext
        Loop
    End With
    ElseIf Arg(1) = "tt" then
    With rs
        .Fields.Append "SortKey", 201, 260 
        .Fields.Append "Txt", 201, 5000 
        .Open
        Do Until Inp.AtEndOfStream
            Lne = Inp.readline
            SortKey = Trim(Mid(Lne, Arg(3), Arg(4) - Arg(3)))
            .AddNew
            .Fields("SortKey").value = SortKey
            .Fields("Txt").value = Lne
            .UpDate
        Loop
        If Arg(2) = "a" then SortColumn = "SortKey ASC"
        If Arg(2) = "d" then SortColumn = "SortKey DESC"
        .Sort = SortColumn
        Do While not .EOF
            Outp.writeline .Fields("Txt").Value
            .MoveNext
        Loop
    End With
    End If
End Sub
```

**Sort**

*filter Sort {n|t|tt} {a|d} StartColumn  EndColumn*

*filter n a 0 8*

Sorts a file

```
n - extracts a number from the columns specified. Looks for the first number.
t - extracts a text string including spaces from the columns specified.
tt - extracts a text string discarding leading and trailing spaces from the columns specified.
a - sorts acending
d - sorts decending
startcolumn - the starting column
endcolumn - the ending column
```

**Example**

*filter sort n a 1 10 < "%windir%\win.ini"*